# How To Set A Timeout For fetchBaseQuery?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

timeout for fetchBaseQuery not working I add timout exactly like documentation in rtk query

but not working

```
const apiSlice = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'api',
  baseQuery: baseQueryWithReauth,
  timeout:1000,
  endpoints: builder => ({}),
  tagTypes: ['User', 'Post', 'Comment', 'Tag', 'Notification'],
  keepUnusedDataFor: 5,
});

export default apiSlice;
```

and here is full code ,
how can make this api call wait for 10 second

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';
import { persistor } from '../../store';
import { logout, setAuthModal, setToken } from '../auth/authSlice';

const baseQuery = fetchBaseQuery({
  baseUrl: process.env.BASE_URL,

  credentials: 'include',
  prepareHeaders: (headers, { getState }) => {
    const token = getState().auth.token;
    if (token) headers.set('authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
    return headers;
  },
});

const baseQueryWithReauth = async (args, api, extraOptions) => {
  let result = await baseQuery(args, api, extraOptions);

  if (result?.error?.originalStatus === 403) {
    // sends refresh token to get new access token
    const refreshResult = await baseQuery('/refresh', api, extraOptions);
    // stores the new token
    if (refreshResult?.data) {
      api.dispatch(setToken(refreshResult.data));
      // retry the original query with new access token
      result = await baseQuery(args, api, extraOptions);
    } else {
      // Logging out
      // 1- deleting refresh token from cookies
      // 2- resetting redux state
      // 3- resetting redux persist
      await baseQuery('/logout', api, extraOptions);
      api.dispatch(logout());
      persistor.purge();

      api.dispatch(setAuthModal(true));
    }
  }

  return result;
};

const apiSlice = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'api',
  baseQuery: baseQueryWithReauth,
  timeout:1000,
  endpoints: builder => ({}),
  tagTypes: ['User', 'Post', 'Comment', 'Tag', 'Notification'],
  keepUnusedDataFor: 5,
});

export default apiSlice;
```

and here is my postapislice

```
import { GiConsoleController } from 'react-icons/gi';
import apiSlice from '../api/apiSlice';
import tagsApiSlice from '../tags/tagsApiSlice';
import usersApiSlice from '../users/usersApiSlice';

const postsApiSlice = apiSlice.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: builder => ({
    getPosts: builder.query({
      query: id => `/posts${id ? `/bookmarked/${id}` : ''}`,
      
      providesTags: (result, err, args) =>
        result
          ? [{ type: 'Post', id: 'LIST' }, ...result.map(({ id }) => ({ type: 'Post', id }))]
          : [{ type: 'Post', id: 'LIST' }],
    }),
    getPost: builder.query({
      query: ({ url }) => `/posts/${url}`,
      providesTags: (result, err, args) =>
        result ? [{ type: 'Post', id: result.id }] : [{ type: 'Post', id: 'LIST' }],
    }),
    createPost: builder.mutation({
      query: ({ ...data }) => ({
        url: `/posts`,
        method: 'POST',
        body: { ...data },
      }),
      invalidatesTags: (result, err, args) =>
        result
          ? [
              { type: 'Comment', id: 'LIST' },
              { type: 'Post', id: result.id },
            ]
          : [{ type: 'Post', id: 'LIST' }],
    }),
    updatePost: builder.mutation({
      query: ({ meta, data }) => ({
        url: `/posts/${meta.url}`,
        method: 'PATCH',
        body: data,
      }),
      invalidatesTags: (result, err, { meta }) => [{ type: 'Post', id: meta.id }],
      async onQueryStarted({ meta: { url } }, { dispatch, queryFulfilled }) {
        const { data: updatedPost } = await queryFulfilled;
        dispatch(
          postsApiSlice.util.updateQueryData('getPost', { url }, draftPost => {
            Object.assign(draftPost, updatedPost);
          })
        );
      },
    }),
    deletePost: builder.mutation({
      query: ({ url, publicId }) => ({
        url: `/posts/${url}`,
        method: 'DELETE',
        body: { publicId },
      }),
      invalidatesTags: (result, err, args) => [{ type: 'Post', id: args.id }],
    }),
    postReaction: builder.mutation({
      query: ({ url, action, userId }) => ({
        url: `/posts/${url}/${action}`,
        method: 'PATCH',
        body: { userId },
      }),
      invalidatesTags: (result, err, { id, toInvalidate }) => [
        {
          type: toInvalidate ? toInvalidate.type : 'Post',
          id: toInvalidate?.id ? toInvalidate.id : id,
        },
      ],
      async onQueryStarted(
        { url, actionKey, immutatedArray, id, toInvalidate },
        { dispatch, queryFulfilled }
      ) {
        const patchResult = dispatch(
          toInvalidate
            ? toInvalidate.type === 'User'
              ? usersApiSlice.util.updateQueryData(
                  'getUser',
                  toInvalidate.extra.username,
                  draftUser => {
                    const foundPost = draftUser.posts.find(post => post.id === id);
                    foundPost[actionKey] = immutatedArray;
                  }
                )
              : toInvalidate.type === 'Tag'
              ? tagsApiSlice.util.updateQueryData(
                  'getTagByName',
                  toInvalidate.extra.name,
                  draftTag => {
                    const foundPost = draftTag.posts.find(post => post.id === id);
                    foundPost[actionKey] = immutatedArray;
                  }
                )
              : postsApiSlice.util.updateQueryData('getPost', { url }, draftPost => {
                  draftPost[actionKey] = immutatedArray;
                })
            : postsApiSlice.util.updateQueryData('getPost', { url }, draftPost => {
                draftPost[actionKey] = immutatedArray;
              })
        );
        try {
          await queryFulfilled;
        } catch {
          patchResult.undo();
          dispatch(
            toInvalidate
              ? toInvalidate.type === 'User'
                ? usersApiSlice.util.invalidateTags([
                    { type: 'User', id: toInvalidate.id },
                    { type: 'User', id: 'LIST' },
                  ])
                : tagsApiSlice.util.invalidateTags([
                    { type: 'Tag', id: toInvalidate.id },
                    { type: 'Tag', id: 'LIST' },
                  ])
              : postsApiSlice.util.invalidateTags([
                  { type: 'Post', id },
                  { type: 'Post', id: 'LIST' },
                ])
          );
        }
      },
    }),
  }),
  overrideExisting: true,
});

export const {
  useGetPostsQuery,
  useGetPostQuery,
  useGetBookmarkedPostsListQuery,
  useCreatePostMutation,
  useUpdatePostMutation,
  useDeletePostMutation,
  usePostReactionMutation,
} = postsApiSlice;

export default postsApiSlice;
```

and here is my post.jsx file

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import tw, { styled } from 'twin.macro';
import LoadingSpinner from '../../../common/LoadingSpinner';
// import PostsList from '../../../common/PostsList';
import { useGetPostsQuery } from '../../../core/features/posts/postsApiSlice';
// import Postslistxx from '../../Tag/Postlistsxx';
// import Posts1 from './Posts1';







import { nanoid } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
  import Post from '../../../common/PostsList/components/Post';
import Placeholder from '../../../common/Placeholder/Placeholder';
import Postsabc from './Postsabc';



// const PostsList = ({ posts, filteredTag, toInvalidate, enableImages = true }) => {

//   return (
//     <Wrapper>
//       {posts?.length > 0 ? (
//         posts.slice( 0 , 5).map((post, i) => (
//           <Post
//             post={post}
//             // isFirstPost={enableImages && i === 0}
//             // filteredTag={filteredTag}
//             // key={nanoid()}
//             // toInvalidate={toInvalidate}
//           />
//         ))
//       ) : (
//         <Placeholder />
//       )}
//     </Wrapper>
//   );
// };







  
const Posts = ({ value }) => {

  const { data: posts, isLoading } = useGetPostsQuery(null, {
    
    refetchOnMountOrArgChange: true, 
  });
  const [filteredPosts, setFilteredPosts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setFilteredPosts(posts?.filter(post => post.title.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())));
  }, [value, posts]);

  return isLoading ? (
    <LoadingSpinner />
  ) : (
    filteredPosts && <Postsabc posts={filteredPosts} enableImages={false} />
  );
};

  const Wrapper = tw.div`bg-blue`;

export default Posts;
```

Comment: @DrewReese trying to find another way ? but still .  i can not .

Comment: @DrewReese  . why i can not resolve this issue . it is impossible . now in 1 month . still no answer for me . tried millions of ways . please give me solution for this . why website fetch all their 5000 records from mongo db . fetch in the main page of website . i even can not make  timeout for it . the problem not going away .

Comment: Well, I *did* point out that by the time the react code is running that the page has already loaded. I also requested clarification what the issue was that you are trying to solve for.

Comment: @DrewReese  let me explain to u . The website in the main page fetch 5 record from database and then plus 2 .(infinity loading) . and it is fine . but there is a request made in network tab and ask for all the records !! . i found the source of problem. it was this line of code .   let result = await baseQuery(args, api, extraOptions);
then i tried to make timer for it . after website loaded that 6 posts . then u come fetch all the posts . i could not make it go away . because it save it for search function in site .please tell me u understand me

Comment: Where is the code that is initiating the queries? Please [edit] to include all relevant code as part of your [mcve].

Comment: @DrewReese i can not understand what u mean . initiating the queries . it fetch all the records from database and save it in localstorage i think . 15 mb in 20 second . i delet the line . search function in site not working . if some one searched in site then u come fetch  . not when site load .

Comment: I think you understood. So is the issue starting with the `useGetPostsQuery` hook in the `Posts` component? Can you step us through the code from there to explain in better detail what the issue is and where the problem is?

Comment: You realize that a timeout means that after X milliseconds, the request is forcefully stopped and your component gets an error, no data? Is that really what you want?

Comment: @phry . i want this fetch api execute after x milisconde . i added timeout before like u said in answer . but it did not worked

Comment: @phry I mean it pulls data in the main page of website . i do not want that . i just it pulls the data from redux just when some one goes to /search page . i got performance issue . because there is 5000 record .

Comment: @DrewReese yes there is data:posts comes . i do not want that , because it fetches all the records . after i add infinity scroll this happened to me

Comment: I think what you might be looking for is using a lazy query, e.g. on-demand, or to use a skip token on the `useGetPostsQuery` to wait for a condition to change and *then* allow the queries to start, see [conditional fetching](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/conditional-fetching).

Comment: @samurai What do you mean by "pulling data"? Making a request? Are you writing code (using the `use...` hook) tp fetch that data on the main site? Because then *you* are telling that to make that request.
Are you maybe looking for `skip`? I'm sorry, it is absolutely unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: X milliseonds after what? After the site rendered? After a user entered data? What is the reason for wanting that X milliseconds anfter the site loaded?

Comment: sorry , i waste your time . i am so dumb . I want make something after site load it waits 10 second . and then excute. maybe it is not possible.

Comment: @DrewReese  u gave me lead about usegetpostquery . and then i did find the source of that . and i fixed the issue by removing that . thanks man u saved me . but i could not make timer for it . but it is ok . atleast u saved me . i could not upvote u .thanks .

Answer (score 1):

`fetchBaseQuery` has a `timeout` option, described [here in the docs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/fetchBaseQuery#timeout).

```js
const baseQuery = fetchBaseQuery({
  baseUrl: process.env.BASE_URL,
  timeout: 1000,
  credentials: 'include',
  prepareHeaders: (headers, { getState }) => {
    const token = getState().auth.token;
    if (token) headers.set('authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
    return headers;
  },
});
```

That `timeout` option you use on `createApi` doesn't exist - please remove it.

PS: that was added in 1.8 or 1.9, if you have an older version, update RTK.

PPS: I'm not perfectly sure that you are using the word "timeout" correctly here, as I see that previously you used the word "polling" for the same thing. Timeout means that after X milliseconds, the request is forcefully stopped and your component gets an error, no data? Is that really what you want?
Maybe go into more detail explaining why you want to do something, not how you technically want to solve it?